# AngularJs logout action

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, single-page-application

I have implemented authentication, based on jwt tokens in my app. But I have some trouble with logout action. When I press logout, I simply clear my local storage from `access_token` value.

Let's imagine, that user opened three browser tabs with my app. One of them is unprotected and there is some unsaved user input (tab1). Other tabs (tab2,tab3) have protected resources. When user press logout button on tab3, I want to redirect him on login page (because he is on protected tab). Also I want to redirect him on login page when he makes tab2 active, because it also has unprotected resources. But I do not want to redirect him from tab1 (because it is unprotected), and I do not want to renew it, because user will loose his input. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** In order to achieve this, you'll need to implement [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

A standard single page application written in angular works over HTTP, which, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol):

> HTTP functions as a request–response protocol in the client–server computing model. A web browser, for example, may be the client and an application running on a computer hosting a web site may be the server. The client submits an HTTP request message to the server. The server, which provides resources such as HTML files and other content, or performs other functions on behalf of the client, returns a response message to the client. The response contains completion status information about the request and may also contain requested content in its message body.

**Request-response** is one of the basic methods of communication between computers. One computer sends a request, the other one sends back a response - it's just so simple (on the surface. The underlying technology handles a lot of stuff, but it's out of the scope in this answer).

But, as with any (simple) technology, it has its constraints. A request contains information about its sender. Upon receiving a request, the server handles it and *sends back a response to the entity that issued the request*.

#### Now let's consider your scenario

You have 3 opened tabs with your app and 2 problems here:

1. Suppose you log out on tab 3. Because you use JWT token authentication (actually any token authentication behaves similarly), the proper log out action consists of just removing the token from your local storage **in the SPA project instance on the tab 3**. The application state of the project in tab 1 and 2 does not change in this case. Also, logging out doesn't require any request to the server, thus no response is send that would somehow notify of the changed authentication status of the user.
2. Even if you'll send a request to the server to notify it about the log out action on the tab 3, **the server does not know about other 2 opened tabs,** because the request holds information only about the entity that issued the request, thus it will just send a response to the third tab.

#### Entering WebSockets

**Note:** Before reading on, I want to mention that I don't have practical experience with websockets, so you can take everything I write with a grain of salt.

Again, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) (highlights are mine):

> The WebSocket protocol makes more interaction between a browser and a website possible, facilitating the real-time data transfer from and to the server. This is made possible by providing a standardized way for the **server to send content to the browser without being solicited** by the client, and allowing for messages to be passed back and forth while keeping the connection open. In this way a two-way (bi-directional) ongoing conversation can take place between a browser and the server.

WebSockets provides a [full-duplex communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_%28telecommunications%29) channel, meaning that the server doesn't only provide responses to client's request, but also initiate data transmission. This solves the second problem mentioned above leaving you the task to solve the first problem - notifying the server about the logging out of the user. Once the server knows that the user has logged out, it communicates this fact to all other clients, thus synchronizing the state of your single page application among all tabs.

Angular doesn't provide websockets support out of the box, but there are  modules that give you the possibility to use them in your project. Just google it.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about some kind of trick. In I have implemented your approach using SignalR before I asked a question))